# Create new column based on missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column that is based on the other columns. product5 is the best, product2 is the second-best. So the new column should use product5 if available. If not, then try product2 etc. It needs to generalise to many columns based on the order of the items specified in the list:

```
cols_pref_inorder = ["product5", "product2", "product"...]
df   product  product2 product5
0    apple    Appl     Apple
1    banan    Banan     NaN
```

I tried:

```
def create(x):
  if pd.notnull(df["product5"]):
     return df["product5"]
  ...

df["Product_final"] = df.apply(create, axis=1)
```

Expected Output

```
df   product  product2 product5 Product_final
0    apple    Appl     Apple     Apple          (Product_final uses product5 since available)
1    banan    Banan    NaN       Banan          (Product_final uses product2 since product5 is missing)
```

Comment: df["Product_final"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["product5"] if x["product5"] else x["product2"], axis=1)

Comment: @Xiaomin while this could work, looping over rows is highly inefficient, and with many columns the syntax would become cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and slice the first column with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Product_final'] = (df.reindex(cols_pref_inorder, axis=1)
                         .bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
                      )
```

Output:

```
   df product product2 product5 Product_final
0   0   apple     Appl    Apple         Apple
1   1   banan    Banan      NaN         Banan
```

Intermediate (reindexed and bfilled) before slicing:

```
  product5 product2 product
0    Apple     Appl   apple
1    Banan    Banan   banan
```